# PHP display multiple pages of database data

Tags: php

I'm using this while statement to show all contents of database...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,question,date,user,numberofcomments,body,locked FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo '<div class="comment">';
    echo '<div class="leftpart">';
    echo "<div class='date'><img src='../assets/icons/Time-info.png'> ".ago($row['date']);
    echo "</div><br><img src='../assets/icons/User-Info.png'> ".$row['user'];
    echo "<br><img src='../assets/icons/Comments.png'> ".$row[numberofcomments];
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="rightpart-topic">';
    if($row['locked']==1) { echo '<img src="../assets/icons/Lock.png" /> ';
    }
    echo '<a href="topic.php?id='.$row[id].'">'.$row['question'].'</a>';
    echo '<br>'.substr($row['body'],0,70).'...';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

I want to show only 10 rows then have links to show the rest (as in page 1,2,3,4, last type thing). How would I go about doing that? It would help if you could also explain your code as it would be greatly appreciated. It helps my learning process.

Thanks!

Comment: You should post your query. You have to use LIMIT and provide an offset to pull only x number per page

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a LIMIT in your query using some sort of passed $_GET variable.

```
$start=0;
$limit = 10;
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? : 0));

$start = $page * $limit;

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id,question,date,user,numberofcomments,body,locked FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT {$start},{$limit}");
```

Should be pretty self explanatory.

If there is not page variable set then you are viewing page 0, or the first 10 results of your database query. If page = 1 then you are going to be viewing $page (value=1) * $limit (10) = $start (now value of 10), which will give you results 10-20 or page 1. etc.

So provide your user a button which can link them to a hard paginated link, or do it ajax.

Each url will need to be like so:

```
http://wwww.yoursite.com/somepage.php?page=1
```

Comment: Hi, what is that (isset($_GET['page']) ? : 0); I don't understand the syntax here.

Comment: That is a [http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-120] (ternary operator) . Basically a condensed IF ELSE statement. Quoting the site on this specific usage: "Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise. "

Answer (score -1):

Efficiency aside, you could simply set a counter and check if it value Is greater than 10 during the loop. If so, add a 'hidden' class to the parent div. That class would use display:none;

Comment: Could you give me a quick example?  I'm a bit fuzzy what all that means. Thanks!